# confused as to why I need to add more constraints to this view

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have the following storyboard and am just trying to pick up autolayout (not a full time ios dev obviously). In this storyboard:

[image]

Obviously, there is a problem but if I tell Xcode to "add missing constraints" it will create what seem to be superfluous constraints like from my blue view to the top.

[image]

I would seem that since I have established a relationship to the orange view that it should be able to figure out the rest. Is this correct? It seems like adding views would cause just a massive proliferation of contraints.

Comment: You have not specified heights of any of the above views. Xcode therefore does it for you but in a weird way..

Comment: @Brandon but shouldn't the heights be filled in automatically? I thought the point was to be able to say - have this view extend from the bottom to 10 pixels short of the orange view? Also, if I set the height, won't it automatically break since different phones have different screen sizes?

Comment: Autolayout needs to be able to work out a location and size for each element (sometimes it can rely on the content in an object such as UILabel but you can still specify a size). I order for autolayout to work best you need to have some items that can "float" as the screen size changes. For example you might want your orange to be a fixed size with the green/blue expanding. In this case you would fix the orange position size, fix the top of green, the bottom of blue, the leading/trailing edge of both and set a vertical space constraint between orange bottom/blue top and orange top/green bottom

Comment: You need to set the height of at least one object otherwise there are multiple solutions

Comment: ah thx @Paulw11 - i specified the height for blue and green and seems like orange was made to stretch. thx!